# Setting Application Default Credentials (ADC) on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

it's my first time to use Google API, now I'm following this tutorial(https://how2electronics.com/diy-ai-camera-with-google-vision-esp32-cam-module/), but I couldn't get the information as tutorial. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM30P.jpg) , in my google cloud, it's just this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXQ5s.png)

Now I installed the google could CLI but there still nothing under the set up authentication....

here is my terminal :

These credentials will be used by any library that requests Application Default Credentials (ADC).

Quota project "esp32-text-369110" was added to ADC which can be used by Google client libraries for billing and quota. Note that some services may still bill the project owning the resource.

Thank you so much

Can anyone tell me which part I missed...I really need the information under the set up authentication

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please include the link to the tutorial that you're following. There are several steps: (1) create a Service Account, (2) create and save a Key for the Service Account; (3) `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` set to the path to the Key; (4) run code using Google libraries that use the value of `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to auth.

Comment: @DazWilkin, service account key file usage is, most of the time, a very bad practice. If you can avoid to advocate on it, it's better! Anyway, after installing gcloud CLI, you have to authenticate yourselves: `gcloud auth login` to use your account with the GCLOUD CLI commands. `gcloud auth application-default login` to use your account with the client libraries in your code.

Comment: Using `gcloud auth application-default login` creates a key too (`application_default_credentials.json`) and one that has **all** the (often "Owner") permissions of the User account. It's good to ensure folks understand the risks of auth mechanisms but it's also unrealistic to assume that people learning Google Cloud employ Workfload Identity Federation particularly when the majority of tutorials create keys.

Comment: https://how2electronics.com/diy-ai-camera-with-google-vision-esp32-cam-module/  here is the tutorial I followed. I'm going to try your suggestions now!! thank you for the replay!!